# ExtraBalDaoWithdraw

Tags: contract-invocation

Can someone please explain more than 2300 withdrawals from the DAO Extra Balance contract that took place today?

https://etherscan.io/address/0x755cdba6AE4F479f7164792B318b2a06c759833B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [Poloniex](https://etherscan.io/address/0x32be343b94f860124dc4fee278fdcbd38c102d88) withdrawing the extraBalance on behalf of it's customers who bought The DAO tokens during the last two weeks of the crowdfunding period.

Let's check one of the batch of recent transactions - [0xfa3b3a60e73a5a4eef8c3dc532a25eb7f726fb73dd42132233dd447bb3fc81be](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xfa3b3a60e73a5a4eef8c3dc532a25eb7f726fb73dd42132233dd447bb3fc81be).
The DAO token holder's address is 0x090c6715b859a9a60e2fe539f09039b9c6ced3ab.

Download [github.com/bokkypoobah/TheDAOData/blob/master/CreatedTokenEventsWithNonZeroExtraBalance_v4.txt](https://github.com/bokkypoobah/TheDAOData/blob/master/CreatedTokenEventsWithNonZeroExtraBalance_v4.txt).

Then run the following command:

```
Iota:Downloads bok$ grep 0x090c6715b859a9a60e2fe539f09039b9c6ced3ab CreatedTokenEventsWithNonZeroExtraBalance_v4.txt
Data    0x32be343b94f860124dc4fee278fdcbd38c102d88  0x090c6715b859a9a60e2fe539f09039b9c6ced3ab  Proxy   1597766 0x8bc311527694535c430add2671deaadc02a8dd890107df323844aec9407e7190  146440487Sat, 28 May 2016 03:07:53 GMT  1.77571437  1.18380958  0.59190479  118.380958  83057   30000000000 0.00249171  77491
```

It is a proxy withdrawal, which is an exchange who bought on behalf of it's customer. And the extraBalance amount of 0.59190479 ETH withdrawn matches the withdrawn amount.

And let's check another recent transaction - [0xf9bf9fa68dcf32dbcb385c449ee556c9201a52df9b13140fc25e10a7e0decd1a](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf9bf9fa68dcf32dbcb385c449ee556c9201a52df9b13140fc25e10a7e0decd1a). The DAO token holder's address is  0xa79febdc5db4c35ac4bbd038b1c0ecd5c975b7d2 .

Checking against the .txt file:

```
Iota:Downloads bok$ grep  0xa79febdc5db4c35ac4bbd038b1c0ecd5c975b7d2  CreatedTokenEventsWithNonZeroExtraBalance_v4.txt 
Data    0x32be343b94f860124dc4fee278fdcbd38c102d88  0xa79febdc5db4c35ac4bbd038b1c0ecd5c975b7d2  Proxy   1598986 0xd8cc7b54af5a9a3e074042f6f4854f893fe4c0c08c468eb08fdc0432eacc1653  146442244Sat, 28 May 2016 08:00:44 GMT  0.4372385   0.291492333333333333    0.145746166666666667    29.1492333333333333 83057   30000000000 0.00249171  78082   
Data    0x32be343b94f860124dc4fee278fdcbd38c102d88  0xa79febdc5db4c35ac4bbd038b1c0ecd5c975b7d2  Proxy   1598992 0x4a221ad32df09725d34e7d1312cd80f13085da54c46b0d9bb0804cc096d6d13d  146442258Sat, 28 May 2016 08:03:06 GMT  2   1.333333333333333333    0.666666666666666667    133.3333333333333333    53057   33237592977 0.001763486970580689    78088
```

It's another proxy withdrawal, and the sum of the extraBalance amount matching the withdrawn amount.

Comment: Updated with further information that it's Poloniex